# org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory Class not found exception when Tomcat 7 server deploy

Tags: database, tomcat

When I start my Tomcat server 7, I am given a warning by mentioning following messages:

> WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException:
>   Could not load resource factory class **[Root exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory]]**

Since this is a warning, I am skipping this and continue the process. Once I create  DataBase connection I am given following exception.

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory]
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:82)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.connection.DBConnectionToolkit.getConnection(DBConnectionToolkit.java:38)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.internalToolkit.WSUserInternalToolkit.isValidUser(WSUserInternalToolkit.java:187)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.toolkit.WSUserToolkit.isValidUser(WSUserToolkit.java:23)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.servlets.AccessTokenServlet.validateCredentials(AccessTokenServlet.java:315)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.servlets.AccessTokenServlet.handlePasswordGrant(AccessTokenServlet.java:139)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.servlets.AccessTokenServlet.handleGrants(AccessTokenServlet.java:86)
    at se.cambiosys.spider.FHIRServermodule.servlets.AccessTokenServlet.doPost(AccessTokenServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory
    at** org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:80)
```

whether I am using wrong jar file in Tomcat server or any other problem?

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource da = (DataSource) 
ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/fhirDB");//error... code snippet.
return da.getConnection();
```

where my ConText file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true">
<!-- path="/CosmicFHIRService" docBase="CosmicFHIRService.war" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" -->

<Resource name="jdbc/fhirDB" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="spider3" password="spider3"
    factory="org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://CSLK-DKDB-81-1:1433;DatabaseName=FAROE_SPIDERIII;SelectMethod=cursor;"
    maxActive="8" />
    <Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to use objectweb stuff? When I look at http://jotm.objectweb.org and http://jotm.ow2.org (if sites are reachable at all) it looks kind of ancient and obsolete. Maybe you should better upgrde to recommanded Apache Tomcat 9 and/or use built in data sources: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: I don't know where this objectweb stuffs are reffered? I think problem is with unwanted jar is placed on my lib folder. But how can I find that?

Comment: It is your `context.xml` file that refers to the class which does not exist: `factory="org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory"` and next reference likely to fail: `<Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory".../>`. You can simply change that.

Comment: Your a genius. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory` is not on your Tomcats' classpath. You'll have to place the .jar-File containing it into Apache Tomcat lib folder: `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/`

Edit:
As per your comment it was not your intention to actually use this class at all. It is your `context.xml` file that refers to the class which does not exist:

`factory="org.objectweb.jndi.DataSourceFactory"`

and next reference likely to fail:

`<Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory".../>`.

You can simply change that to alternative implementations and update further attributes if necessary as descripted in [Apache Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).